# Paypal API Rest, integration in Symfony project

Tags: php, rest, paypal, symfony

I'm coming to desperatly try to find help about a error that even the paypal technical support still didn't achieve to understand...

This is the error returned : "Attempted to load class "ApiContext" from namespace "PayPal\Rest".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?"

I installed the paypal api via composer, and here is the code using this api. I followed the documentation steps by steps, so I really don't understand this error... the use statements are all there... :

```
<?php

namespace PlatformBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;

class PaypalController extends Controller
{
    private function paypalKeys()
    {
        return new ApiContext(
            new OAuthTokenCredential(
                'AUWLQ9xMRA54XpqgX_Bbd0koHkIzfAFnZSPXipGbIZAqVnJCaWj5B4hga5dbd2UE0diElegudMDR9dj0',
                'EPStewzop-DjMhdyvw51TJBnpZUHt6hGahwmRSDljIhYmDVGMPXsAV0oWoMiCcQpVdXsyOdnZJN1yRZC'
            )
        );
    }

    public function chargeAction()
    {
        $this->paypalKeys();
        $price = 10;
        $total = $price;

        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $item = new Item();
        $item->setName('transfer')
            ->setCurrency('eur')
            ->setQuantity(1)
            ->setPrice($price);

        $itemList = new ItemList();
        $itemList->setItems([$item]);

        $details = new Details();
        $details->setShipping(0)
            ->setSubtotal($price);

        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('eur')
            ->setTotal($total)
            ->setDetails($details);

        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($itemList)
            ->setDescription('Description')
            ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

        $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl('http://localhost/dublin/web/app_dev.php/admin')
            ->setCancelUrl('http://localhost/dublin/web/app_dev.php/cancel');

        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('sale')
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
            ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

//        try {
        $payment->create($this->paypalKeys());
//        } catch (Exception $e) {
//            die($e);
//        }
//
//        return new Response('true');
//        echo $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: I strongly sugges you use existing bundles when available. https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I tried that one as well but I failed to do it either

Comment: WARNING: You leaked your OAuth token, if you plan to use this token in production you **must** change it.